# Designing a staging table to import data

Tags: sql-server, ssis, staging-table

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition
After setting an SSIS package that imports data from a flat file, I wanted to know how would I proceed to insert data into staging tables and what the structure of staging tables is?

Comment: SSIS is meant to do away with staging tables. You should be able to transform the data on the fly and import into your destination table, without having to use staging tables

Comment: I need staging tables, so that i would be able to validate data using stored procedures and see errors that occures before inserting in databases. Staging tables are very important here

Comment: If you are going to stage the data I would design the tables to match the design of the source files. This makes back tracking errors easier.

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to stage data in temporary database so that i can handle errors before inserting in the real database taget. So my main question is " What is the structure of a staging table and how can we handle errors before inserting in the real taget database"

Comment: @Raj, I think staging tables are still very useful. Particularly when the data one is importing is of unknown quality or coming from a 3rd party with weak support--for example, I have a few packages that utilize APIs which import to staging tables with nvarchar dataypes with liberal sizing. I then manage the data quality by transforming to another set of  tables with the expected datatypes/sizing.  This is an old tactic, however, very effective in pumping 24/7 data through with as few errors as possible on the imports themselves. With that said, fez's answer is  a good alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite hard to answer your question without any sample input/output but in general, I would create the temp stage table with the same data types to match the source files (as destination-data mentioned above). Then, you can use [Derived Column Transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms141069.aspx) to transform the data to match your business logic before using a [Data Flow Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms141122.aspx) to insert the transformed data into your destination table(s).

You can add error handling to the Derived Column step by selecting 'Configure Error Output', there is a good example of how to do this [here](http://www.josefrichberg.com/journal/2012/2/1/using-the-error-output-of-the-derived-column.html):

Hope this helps.